# Problems extending CI library Form_validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, continuous-integration

I have tried to extend the Form_validation library from Codeigniter with no success.

I have two functions that I'd like in this extended class but when the validation is run i get these messages in the log:

> DEBUG - 06-07-2016 11:20:33 --> Unable to find validation rule: checkAccountnameForUpdate
>   DEBUG - 06-07-2016 11:20:33 --> Unable to find validation rule: checkEmailForUpdate

Here is my extended class which is placed in

> application/libraries

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation 
{
    public function __construct($rules = array())
    {
        // Pass the $rules to the parent constructor.
        parent::__construct($rules);
        // $this->CI is assigned in the parent constructor, no need to do it here.
    }

    public function checkAccountnameForUpdate($accountname, $id)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public function checkEmailForUpdate($email, $id)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And here's my rules:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('editAccountname', 'Brugernavn', 'required|checkAccountnameForUpdate[hiddenField]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('editEmail', 'Email', 'required|checkEmailForUpdate[hiddenField]');
$this->form_validation->set_message('checkAccountnameForUpdate', 'Test2');
$this->form_validation->set_message('checkEmailForUpdate', 'Test');
// hiddenField is the name of a hiddenField containing the users ID.
```

I've googled around and tired some different stuff. I have no idea why it doesn't work.

EDIT 1:

I've tried to replace

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('editAccountname', 'Brugernavn', 'required|checkAccountnameForUpdate[hiddenField]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('editEmail', 'Email', 'required|checkEmailForUpdate[hiddenField]');
```

to

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('editAccountname', 'Brugernavn', 'required|checkAccountnameForUpdate');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('editEmail', 'Email', 'required|checkEmailForUpdate');
```

No changes.

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter 3 ?

Comment: You are expecting 2 variables being passed in your function, but the `set_rules` only sends one per rule. In this case `$this->input->post('editAccountName')`, you are also missing the `$this->form_validation->set_message()` for both functions.

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty - Yes CI3.

Comment: @Jordy - I have the set_message(). It has been included in the main post. But i read that I could pass two variables this way. Does it only count with callbacks?

Comment: I have used your exact approach, including passing two arguments, and it works perfectly. I don't see why you are having problems. No other error messages?

Comment: @DFriend could you share your code?

Comment: Code shared, complete with demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my extension to the validation library. I have left a few functions out as they are site specific but do not affect the demo here.

APPPATH/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
  public function __construct($rules = array())
  {
    parent :: __construct($rules);
  }

  /*
   * reformats the input to ###-###-#### and returns formatted string, 
   * if it cannot accomplish the format (of a non-empty input) it returns FALSE.
   */
  public function phone_format($phone)
  {
    if(empty($phone))
    {
      //assume an empty field is OK. 
      //There needs to be a required rule to check a required field and that rule should
      //be before this one in the list of rules
      return TRUE;
    }
    $phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $phone);
    $newPhone = preg_replace("/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "$1-$2-$3", $phone);
    if(preg_match('/((\d){3})?(\-){1}(\d){3}(\-){1}(\d){4}/', $newPhone))
    {
      //preg_replace was able to reformat it to the correct pattern - must be good
      return $newPhone;
    }
    return FALSE;
  }

  /**
   * field validation for zipcode
   */
  public function check_zipcode($zipcode)
  {
    $result = (bool) preg_match("/^([0-9]{5})(-[0-9]{4})?$/i", $zipcode);
    return $result;
  }
}
```

We can test this class with the simple controller and view shown below. The test uses the `phone_format` validator function.

A couple things to note about how I'm using `form_validation->set_rules()`.

First, I pass an array of rules instead of the usually demonstrated pipe separated string. eg. "trim|required". Why? Because `set_rules()` turns the string into an array anyway so why make it do the extra work?

Second. Notice I am passing a fourth argument. The fourth argument is not well documented. Its use is shown in the [Setting Error Messages](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#id21) section but it is not described in the [Class Reference](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#CI_Form_validation::set_rules) section of the documentation. The argument accepts an array of error messages in the form ['rule_name' => 'This is the error message'].

I'm also in the habit of using the short syntax to create arrays eg. `$this->data = [];` instead of  `$this->data = array();` mostly because it's less typing.

Here's the test controller Testcase.php

```
class Testcase extends CI_Controller
{
  protected $data;

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data = [];
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
  }

  public function test_validation()
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone'
      , ['trim', 'required', 'phone_format']
      , [
          'phone_format' => 'Not a valid phone number.', 
          'required' => '<em>{field}</em> required.'
        ]
    );

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
      $this->load->view('test_form_v', $this->data);
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Passed Validation<br>";
      echo $_POST['phone'];
    }
  }

}
```

And here is the view file test_form_v.php

```
<?php    
echo form_open('testcase/test_validation');
echo form_input('phone', set_value('phone'));
echo form_error('phone');
echo form_submit('Submit', 'Submit');
echo form_close();
```

Run it by entering this url in a browser `your_doman.whatever/testcase/test_validation`

Submit without entering any input and you get the required error. Submit "123456789" and you get the invalid phone number error message. Submit "1234567890" and you get

> Passed Validation
>
> 123-456-7890

This demonstrates that the extend class and its new validator works. I hope this helps you figure out your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help here but It still doesn't work. I've even set the Form_validation library to autoload.

Comment: Did you create a simple 'testcase' controller as I presented? Doing so could help you narrow down where the problem might be.

Comment: I've found out that it doesn't even call the functions in the extended library. When i set the functions to do nothing but return TRUE it also gives me validation error.